# POST req.body is empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post

Issue occurs when I send any request via `curl` or `hurl` test. `req.headers['content-length']` returns the correct length and `req.headers['content-type']` is correct, but `req.body` returns `{}`.

Hurl test:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/v1/fragments
Content-Type: text/plain

[BasicAuth]
user1@email.com:password1
`This is a fragment!`
```

Equivalent `curl` command:

```
curl -i \
  -X POST \
  -u user1@email.com:password1 \
  -H "Content-Type: text/plain" \
  -d "This is a fragment" \
  https://localhost:8080/v1/fragments
```

React code where `router` = `express.Router()`:

```js
router.post('/fragments', (req, res) => {
    let newuuid = uuidv4();
    res.location(`http://localhost:8080${req.originalUrl}/${newuuid}`)
        .status(201)
        .json(
            createSuccessResponse({
                fragment: {
                    id: newuuid,
                    ownerId: '11d4c22e42c8f61feaba154683dea407b101cfd90987dda9e342843263ca420a',
                    created: '2021-11-02T15:09:50.403Z',
                    updated: '2021-11-02T15:09:50.403Z',
                    type: req.headers['content-type'],
                    size: Number(req.headers['content-length']),
                },
            })
        );
});
```

Comment: What is `router`? Do you have a body parser?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. It seems you are posting server code and not the code of the request.  My guess is that it's not Content-Type text/plain but application/json

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I was using `app.use(bodyParser.json());` wehen sending `text/plain` content instead of `app.use(bodyParser.text());`.

Comment: Why? The request doesn't contain JSON.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).